# Obtain Docusign Access Code via typescript httpClient.post

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, post, httpclient, docusignapi

I need some assistance in getting the access token via the docusign api. Below is my code with the error i am seeing in xcode. Testing via postman returns an access code but i cannot get it to work via the app (running on native device, or in browser). Running in a browser give me a CORS error, but that was to be expected. Why it errors on an iphone, I can't figure out.

I am using ionic, typescript. Most of the examples i see are using express with massive amounts of code I don't understand how to integrate into the ionic project. If there is a lot more that goes into this than some minor fixes, i'd be willing to hire someone to get it running.

Thanks

```
//docusign access token using authorization code
             const post_data = {
              'code': this.dsAuthCode,
              'grant_type': "authorization_code"
            }
    
            // Http Options
             const httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                  'Authorization': "Basic " + b64ds
                })
              }
    
          this.httpClient.post('https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token', post_data, httpOptions)
          .subscribe((data:any) => {
              this.dsAccessToken = data.access_token
              console.log('Access Token ', data.access_token)
              //this.docsignUserURI(data.access_token)
          }, error => {
              console.log('access token error', JSON.stringify(error));
          });


access token error {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how mine is working now. I get the access code from a web docusign popup then pass it into a Firebase Cloud Functions callable https request using 'request-promise' to return a promise.

```
.ts page:

async docsignAccessToken(){
   //this.dsAuthCode is a two sided [(ngModel)} on the html page
   // the docusign authorize code is pasted before running this functions
      console.log('starting access token, authcode = ', this.dsAuthCode)

      var fbdsAuth = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('dsAuth');
      fbdsAuth({dsAuthCode: this.dsAuthCode, b64ds: b64ds}).then(function(result) {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    this.dsAccessToken = JSON.parse(result.data).access_token
    //this.docsignUserURI(data.access_token)
    // ...
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Getting the Error details.
        var code = error.code;
        var message = error.message;
        var details = error.details;
        console.log(error)
        // ...
    });  

  }



firebase cloud functions:

    export const dsAuth = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    
    
          var request = require('request-promise');;
          var options = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token',
            'headers': {
              'Authorization': 'Basic ' + data.b64ds,
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            form: {
              'code': data.dsAuthCode,
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
            }
          };
          return request(options, function (error, response) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(response.body);
          });
    
        });
```